# Converting address of a location into lattitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to convert address entered by user into lattitude and longitude in nodejs and i wrote the following code but the error is coming which is mentioned below the code,thanks in advance

```
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
var request = require('request');
var response = require('response');

var options = {
  provider: 'google',

  // Optional depending on the providers 
  httpAdapter: 'http', 
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCJbAJT1DcvuKGDncrTs3Q4pY3hWAixOYI',  
  formatter: 'string'       // 'gpx', 'string', ... 
};

var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

// Using callback 
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
});

// Or using Promise 
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris')
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

> throw new Error('StringFormatter need a pattern');
>           ^
>
> Error: StringFormatter need a pattern

Comment: You should not post sensitive information here, such as your api key....

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you have have specified the formatter as `string`.

Change the options parameters `formatter` to `null` and `provider` to `https` and it should work.

```
var options = {
  provider: 'google',
  httpAdapter: 'https', 
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',  
  formatter: null     
};
```

If you want to use the string result formatter you need to specify `options.formatterPattern` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/nchaulet/node-geocoder#formatter)